# Query to list all parents of a hierarchical category in column wise with category group

Tags: sql, postgresql, hierarchical-data, recursive-query

I have 3 Table one is `categories`

```
 id    |    name             |    parentid       |   categorygroupid
---------------------------------------------------------------------
  1         Fruits                    0                    1
  2         Citrus Fruits             1                    2
  3         Oranges                   2                    3
  4         Limes                     2                    3
  5         Melons                    1                    2
  6         watermelons               5                    3
  7         vegetables                0                    1
  8         onion                     7                    3
  9         potato                    7                    3
---------------------------------------------------------------------


CREATE TABLE categories
(
    id bigint ,
    name character varying(100) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    parentid bigint,
    categorygroupid bigint
)

insert into categories (id,name,parentid,categorygroupid)values('1','Fruits','0','1');
insert into categories (id,name,parentid,categorygroupid)values('2','Citrus Fruits','1','2');
insert into categories (id,name,parentid,categorygroupid)values('3','Oranges','2','3');
insert into categories (id,name,parentid,categorygroupid)values('4','Limes','2','3');
insert into categories (id,name,parentid,categorygroupid)values('5','Melons','1','2');
insert into categories (id,name,parentid,categorygroupid)values('6','watermelons','5','3');
insert into categories (id,name,parentId,categorygroupid)values('7','vegetables','0','1');
insert into categories (id,name,parentid,categorygroupid)values('8','onion','7','3');
insert into categories (id,name,parentid,categorygroupid)values('9','potato','7','3');
```

and second table is `categorygroups`

```
 id     groupname    
 ------------------------
  1     Item Group
  2     Category Type
  3     Category
 ------------------------

CREATE TABLE categorygroups
(
    id bigint ,
    groupname character varying(150) COLLATE pg_catalog."default"
)

insert into categorygroups(id,groupname)values('1','Item Group');
insert into categorygroups(id,groupname)values('2','Category Type');
insert into categorygroups(id,groupname)values('3','Category');
```

and third table is `items`

```
id   |    itemname      |    categoryid
------------------------------------------
1        ABC-ORANGE              3
2        DEF-ORANGE              3
3        AB-WaterMelons          5
4        MN-onion                8
5        PQ-potato               9
------------------------------------------

CREATE TABLE items
(
    id bigint ,
    itemname character varying(250) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    categoryid bigint
)

insert into items (id,itemname,categoryid)values('1','ABC-ORANGE','3');
insert into items (id,itemname,categoryid)values('2','DEF-ORANGE','3');
insert into items (id,itemname,categoryid)values('3','AB-Melons','5');
insert into items (id,itemname,categoryid)values('4','MN-onion','8');
insert into items (id,itemname,categoryid)values('5','PQ-potato','9');
```

I want a help to build a query (mysql/postgres) to get the following **result**

```
id | itemname    |  Item Group | Category Type  |   Category
---------------------------------------------------------------
1  | ABC-ORANGE  |   Fruits    | Citrus Fruits  |  Oranges
2  | DEF-ORANGE  |   Fruits    | Citrus Fruits  |  Oranges
3  | AB-Melons   |   Fruits    | Melons         |  watermelons
4  | MN-onion    |   vegetables|                |  onion   
5  | PQ-potato   |   vegetables|                |  potato
```

---

In result columns `Item Group` , `Category Type` and `Category` are three records ( it will increase ) in `categorygroups` table and we will show the category or parent category of an item in the above mentioned column.

for eg:- In the above result item ***ABC-ORANGE*** assigned a category
***Oranges*** and this category have a group ***Category*** . so in result category name  ***Oranges*** will show in ***Category*** column  and this category ( ***Oranges*** ) have a parent ( ***Citrus Fruits*** ) and this parent have group ( ***Category Type*** ). so the parent category name ***Citrus Fruits*** will show in  ***Category Type*** column.

Comment: You did a great job providing DDL and SQL to build a test case. You could improve it by adding foreign key constraints. Please also add description of what you expect to be displayed in  `Item Group` , `Category Type` and `Category`.

Comment: I have added description about result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See working example with fiddle here using the sample data provided. Please share how this works with your real data or additional test samples.

**Schema (PostgreSQL v11)**

**Query #1**

```
WITH all_categories AS (
    SELECT
        c.*,
        cg.groupname
    FROM
        categories c
    INNER JOIN
        categorygroups cg ON cg.id = c.categorygroupid
)
SELECT
    i.id,
    i.itemname,
    COALESCE(ig.name,'') as "Item Group",
    COALESCE(ct.name,'') as "Category Type",   
    c.name as "Category"
FROM
    items i
LEFT JOIN
    all_categories c ON i.categoryid = c.id
LEFT JOIN
    all_categories ct ON c.parentid = ct.id  AND
                         ct.groupname = 'Category Type'
LEFT JOIN
    all_categories ig ON (ct.parentid = ig.id or c.parentid=ig.id ) AND
                         ig.groupname = 'Item Group' 
ORDER BY i.id;
```

| id | itemname | Item Group | Category Type | Category |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | ABC-ORANGE | Fruits | Citrus Fruits | Oranges |
| 2 | DEF-ORANGE | Fruits | Citrus Fruits | Oranges |
| 3 | AB-Melons | Fruits | Melons | watermelons |
| 4 | MN-onion | vegetables |  | onion |
| 5 | PQ-potato | vegetables |  | potato |

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/u5Jr24UGiypBRppmMf561G/2)

Comment: Thank You, This is working. Can you make it as dynamic? i mean `categorygroups`  records are not fixed. it will vary

Comment: This will work even if the categorygroups have different ids as long as the names of the category group remain the same. If they change, then you may simply modify the conditions in the joins. If this is not what you mean by "dynamic", could you share another sample to represent this.

Comment: I mean, if I add another record in { categorygroups } . I need to add another join query with that group name. can you make it this join query dynamic depends on { categorygroups } .  ( if using function or procedure  are ok for me )

Comment: This answer focuses on answering the initial question shared and provides the desired projection of `id | itemname    |  Item Group | Category Type  |   Category`. This seems as if in addition to this projection, you are interested in generating a dynamic query using psql. Please use another question on S/O to ask how to generate a dynamic sql/procedure/function based on the change in categorygroups. You may also reference this question and share what the change in the desired output would be based on changes in parameters to this procedure or in dataset.